# What language versions exist for Assassin’s Creed Syndicate (PS4)?

Tags: ps4, region-lock, assassins-creed-syndicate

**Having a physical blu-ray disc (PS4) in mind: What different language versions of Assassin’s Creed Syndicate exist?**

I believe that all different *editions* (Standard/Rooks/Gold/...) actually share the same disc and the additional content are DLC codes only.

I’ve heard that there is a Russian version, which has menu/voice/subtitles in Russian and English only.

And there is the version for Europe, I believe, having menu/subtitles in English and a bunch of European(?) languages and audio in a couple of European languages.

**Who knows what discs exists exactly? What exact languages do they contain (or allow download for... in all regional PSN stores)?**

Comment: @Frank ubisoft makes it hard to determine (from the outside) which languages a version of the game supports. – I’m multilingual and wish to determine how much language fun this game can deliver with it’s different language versions. For that I need to know which versions exist and what they contain.

Answer (score 1):

The EU version of the game has the following **subtitles** available:

​​English, French, Italian, German, Spanish, Polish, NL (Dutch?), Czech, Hungarian, Chinese (traditional), Chinese (simplified), Korean, SCAN, BRA

The EU version has the following audio **languages** available:

English, French, Italian, German, Spanish

You may need to change the [localisation setting on your PS4](https://manuals.playstation.net/document/gb/ps4/settings/syslanguage.html) itself to make more languages available to you in the game.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/368500/Assassins_Creed_Syndicate/?l=english) (Yes, I know this question is asking about PS4, but still), there's 19 language available, which is:

- English, that comes with interface, full audio, subtitle
- French, that comes with interface, full audio, subtitle
- Italian, that comes with interface, full audio, subtitle
- German, that comes with interface, full audio, subtitle
- Spanish, that comes with interface, full audio, subtitle
- Czech, that comes with interface, subtitle
- Dutch, that comes with interface, subtitle
- Hungarian, that comes with interface, subtitle
- Japanese, that comes with interface, full audio, subtitle
- Korean, that comes with interface, subtitle
- Polish, that comes with interface, subtitle
- Portuguese, that comes with interface, full audio, subtitle
- Russian, that comes with interface, full audio, subtitle
- Simplified Chinese, that comes with interface, subtitle
- Traditional Chinese, that comes with interface, subtitle
- Danish, that comes with subtitle
- Finnish, that comes with subtitle
- Norwegians, that comes with subtitle
- Swedish, that comes with subtitle

I don't doubt PS4 is being same as PC version.